# Allow macOS to use nameservers provided by tap0 interface

Tags: macos, network, vpn, dns

I have a script that establishes a VPN connection and assigns an address to tap0 via DHCP. It looks like the DHCP server is providing nameserver entries (in resolver #2):

```
$scutil --dns
DNS configuration

 resolver #1
 nameserver[0] : 1.1.1.1
 nameserver[1] : 8.8.8.8
 flags    : Request A records
 reach    : Reachable

<snip>

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
 nameserver[0] : 1.1.1.1
 nameserver[1] : 8.8.8.8
 if_index : 4 (en0)
 flags    : Scoped, Request A records
 reach    : Reachable

resolver #2
 search domain[0] : sub.domain.com
 nameserver[0] : 192.168.A.X
 nameserver[1] : 192.168.B.X
 nameserver[2] : 192.168.C.X
 if_index : 9 (tap0)
 flags    : Scoped, Request A records
 reach    : Reachable, Directly Reachable Address
```

However this is not made available to the OS:

```
$ networksetup -getdnsservers Ethernet
1.1.1.1
8.8.8.8
```

What's a good way to augment my script to put the new nameservers as top priority while the tap0 interface has an address?

Thanks!